# Firebase storage with getDownloadURL is it better to retrieve a file with the url everytime needed or to download it to the client once?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

In an app, an avatar could be displayed at many places.
If I use

```js
getDownloadURL(avatarRef).then(url => {
  imgList.map(img => img.src = url);
})
```

is my app billed every time an img download the url?
If so I think the better way is to download the image with xhr once and store it in the app like this

```js
getDownloadURL(avatarRef).then(url => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  let blob;
  xhr.onload = (event) => {
  blob = xhr.response;
};
    
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
// when the blob is returned
imgList.map(img => img.src = URL.creatObjectURL(blob);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get charged every time the data for the image is read from Cloud Storage. So it's indeed best to cache images that are displayed multiple times.

But depending on where your code runs, that may already happen. For example browsers quite aggressively cache images.

If your environment doesn't yet cache the images, you can store them yourself using the download URL as the key/basis for the file name.